# Firebase Functions v2: Can an instance spun up for functionX can receive traffic for functionY?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

[Firebase function v2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta) is here.
Now as per the docs:

> Function instances can now execute more than one request at a time. This feature is available for functions with one dedicated CPU or higher. Concurrency levels can be set on a per-function basis or across all functions with the setGlobalOptions method. If unspecified, new functions with 1 dedicated CPU or higher will default to 80 concurrent requests. See Allow concurrent requests.

Now my doubt is if a Function instance spun up for handling `functionX` will also receive traffic for `functionY`? OR, this means `functionX` instance will receive concurrent traffic only for just `functionX`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebaser here. An instance of `functionX` will only receive concurrent traffic for `functionX`. In Cloud Functions for Firebase, an instance always only consists of a single function (`functionX` or `functionY`, never both).